# How can I create byte values from integers in Python?

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino, pyserial

Background: I need to send a numerical value as a byte to an external device, but I have run into a problem.
My code is:

```
ser=serial.Serial("COM3",9600, timeout=0)
ser.write(value)
```

where "value" is an int that I read have read.  The problem is, when I send this, it sends the character value, not the actual value (it sends the byte value 31 for the number 5, since that is the unicode position for it, I believe)

In reality, I want to be able to send it the character "\x05" for example.  I guess my question is, how would I convert and int 5 to a char "\x05", or 37 to "\x37"

Answer (score 8):

Use the built-in function [`chr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr).

If you have a list of such integers you need to send, you might consider using a [`bytearray()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#bytearray).

Alternatively, in newer versions of Python you can simply use a `byte` type.

Answer (score 5):

you can use this..

```
bytes(chr(my_int))    # not strictly correct unless 0<=my_int<=255
bytes((my_int,))
```

Comment: The first one fails, at least in Python 3, because it's trying to convert a string into bytes without specifying an encoding. (Note to readers, see http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html if encoding issues are new to you.) The second one works great. If the trailing comma used to create a tuple looks bad to you, you can also do something like `bytes([5])`.

Comment: The second one fails under Python 2, where `bytes((1,))` returns the string `'(1,)'`.  Under Python 3 this returns `b'\x01'`.  So don't use either of these if you expect to support both Python 2 and 3.