# Can't send integers with pyserial

Tags: python, python-3.6, pyserial

I want to send the decimal value 236 via an RS232 wire, so I am using pyserial with the following piece of code:

```
ser.write(bytes(236))
```

with this code, it stays in an infinit loop and the process crashes. So i tried this:

```
ser.write(b'\xEC')
```

This works great! But i want to use variable values so an integer would be much more usable.

What is wrong with the first line of code?

Comment: Have a look at this question this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645188/how-can-i-create-byte-values-from-integers-in-python

Answer (score 1):

"bytes(236)" is giving you an array 236 bytes, with a default value of 0...  not what you are looking for.

`com.write(chr(236).encode("latin1"))`

should get your byte moving across the serial port.  Please post more detail on the actual error that you are getting if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Change "com" to "res" in order to match original question